# Array replacing elements that i dont want

Tags: c, file, strtok

I want to put each of this words in a array.

[image: Words that i'm trying to print.]

And here is the code.

[image]

And here is the output

[image]

From what i can understand each time i have a new line the first word of the array is replaced by the fisrt word of the next line of the file, but i dont understand why.
I ditnt show here but after the new line all the other positions are all wrong.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 256

void usage (const char *prog) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Usage (words): %s [file_path]\n", prog);
    exit (1);
}

void split_print_words (const char *filename) {
    FILE *fd = stdin;  // By default will read from stdin
    if (filename != NULL && strcmp (filename, "-") != 0) {
        // A file name was given, let's open it to read from there
        fd = fopen (filename, "r");
        assert (fd != NULL);
    }

    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fd != NULL)) {
        char *token;
        token = strtok(buffer, " \n");
        while(token!=NULL) {
            write(1, token, strlen(token));
            write(1, "\n", 1);
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Check there is one and only one argument
    if (argc < 1 || argc > 2) {
        usage (argv[0]);
    }

    split_print_words (argv[1]);

    exit (0);
}
```

Comment: Please include code and example input/output as text, not as blurry images.

Comment: There is photos of the input and outpute and code and i can see well

Comment: But we don’t want photos, we want text that we can copy and paste. See: [mre]

Comment: Why is your strtok delimiter " \t\n" ? If you want to split the sentence to words, your delimiter should simply be a space: " ".
Also, looks like you are printing words[0] everytime, instead of words[nwords].

Comment: I send the code

Comment: Even with just the " " it doesnt work

Comment: Hi, what's the expected output of your program?

Comment: Passing `fd == NULL` as the third argument to `fgets` is a bug. That will [probably] evaluate to 0 (i.e. `NULL`). You want the third arg to [simply] be: `fd`. You want: `while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fd) != NULL) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (read the comments):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 256
#define WORDS_N 10

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp;

    // Open the file and check if it was opened
    fp = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
      perror("Failed: ");
      return 1;
    }

    // Temporary buffer that will store one line of the file at a time
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    // NULL-initialized 2D array of size 'WORDS_N' x 'MAX_LINE_LEN'
    char words[WORDS_N][MAX_LINE_LEN] = {0};
    // Count how many words we actually read from the file
    int count = 0;
    // To be used by 'strtok()'
    char* pch;
    // Read file line by line
    while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp))
    {
        // Remove trailing newline
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
        //printf("%s\n", buffer);

        // Split line by whitespace
        pch = strtok(buffer, " ");
        // For each token in the split line
        while (pch != NULL)
        {
          // If the array has available space
          if(count < WORDS_N)
            // Put the current token into the array
            strcpy(words[count++], pch);
          //printf ("%s\n", pch);

          // Proceed to next token
          pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }

    // Print array
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);

    // Close file
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Input (myfile.txt):

```
This is a
test and is
not working!
```

Output:

```
This
is
a
test
and
is
not
working!
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, You should replace this:

```c
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fd != NULL)) {
```

with this:

```c
while((fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fd)) != NULL) {
```

I'm not sure how you've set up your compiler. I clearly got a warning from gcc when I compiled your code:

```
arrayreplace.c: In function ‘split_print_words’:
arrayreplace.c:27:48: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘fgets’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   27 |         while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fd != NULL)) {
      |                                                ^
      |                                                |
      |                                                int
In file included from arrayreplace.c:3:
/usr/include/stdio.h:564:69: note: expected ‘FILE * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
  564 | extern char *fgets (char *__restrict __s, int __n, FILE *__restrict __stream)
      |                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

After making this change, I was able to see all words being parsed from file:

```
src : $ cat wordsarr.txt 
This ia a
test and is
not working
src : $ ./a.out wordsarr.txt 
This
ia
a
test
and
is
not
working
```